# How to filter a specific verb in getActivities in GetStream

Tags: java, getstream-io

I'm looking for a way to apply a filter by verb on `feed.getActivities()` in GetStream API, more than lg_te or etc. I want to filter verb to be equals something like `writeArticle`. Is there any way? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: OK, so this question makes almost zero sense **until** you look at the tags.  So if you wanted to clarify it to make it clearer, what you should have explained what you mean by "a feed".  But right now, there is no point in trying to fix the question.  You have received (and accepted) your answer, and the clear answer is that it is not possible.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just edited the question to be more clear. I hope I did it well and it's be enough. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

For these activities, put them into a separate feed and read directly and make your original feed to follow this new feed.

- Your current follow: add to X
- Your new follow: add to article feed and X will follow article feed so everything as before.

But now you can filter, just read article feed.